# Add Polymer support to other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I made a polymer web-app and am now trying to make it work in Firefox and other browsers apart from Chrome. As far as I can understand the current situation importing webcomponents should be enough:

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

But Firefox just shows a blank page. What am I missing?

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/browsers  suggests using the following code:

```
(function() {
  if ('registerElement' in document
      && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
      && 'content' in document.createElement('template')) {
    // platform is good!
  } else {
    // polyfill the platform!
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponentslite.min.js';
    document.body.appendChild(e);
  }
})();
```

but I don't know where to use this? Neither the `<head>` nor the `<body>` seem to work... :(

Happy for any help!

Tried replacing the code snippets from above with the following code snippet but unfortunately with no success:

```
<script>
  // Setup Polymer options
  window.Polymer = {
    dom: 'shadow',
    lazyRegister: true
  };
  // Load webcomponentsjs polyfill if browser does not support native Web Components
  (function() {
    'use strict';
    var onload = function() {
      // For native Imports, manually fire WebComponentsReady so user code
      // can use the same code path for native and polyfill'd imports.
      if (!window.HTMLImports) {
        document.dispatchEvent(
          new CustomEvent('WebComponentsReady', {bubbles: true})
        );
      }
    };
    var webComponentsSupported = (
      'registerElement' in document
      && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
      && 'content' in document.createElement('template')
    );
    if (!webComponentsSupported) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.async = true;
      script.src = 'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js';
      script.onload = onload;
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    } else {
      onload();
    }
  })();
</script>
```

This is my full index.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>

    <title>unibz.club</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="480">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

    <!--icons-->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#017ae4">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <script>
      // Setup Polymer options
      window.Polymer = {
        dom: 'shadow',
        lazyRegister: true
      };
      // Load webcomponentsjs polyfill if browser does not support native Web Components
      (function() {
        'use strict';
        var onload = function() {
          // For native Imports, manually fire WebComponentsReady so user code
          // can use the same code path for native and polyfill'd imports.
          if (!window.HTMLImports) {
            document.dispatchEvent(
              new CustomEvent('WebComponentsReady', {bubbles: true})
            );
          }
        };
        var webComponentsSupported = (
          'registerElement' in document
          && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
          && 'content' in document.createElement('template')
        );
        if (!webComponentsSupported) {
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.async = true;
          script.src = 'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js';
          script.onload = onload;
          document.head.appendChild(script);
        } else {
          onload();
        }
      })();
    </script>

    <script src="bower_components/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/platinum-sw/platinum-sw-elements.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">
    <link rel="import" href="src/my-app/my-app.html">
    <style type="text/css">

      my-app {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 360px;
        height: 100%;
        overflow:auto;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "apikey",
        authDomain: "authurl",
        databaseURL: "dataurl",
        storageBucket: "bucketurl",
        messagingSenderId: "messId"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
      <platinum-sw-register
          auto-register
          skip-waiting
          clients-claim
          reload-on-install
          href="sw-import.js">
        <platinum-sw-cache
            default-cache-strategy="networkFirst">
        </platinum-sw-cache>
      </platinum-sw-register>

      <my-app></my-app>
    </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The suggestion from the docs was an optimization. It avoids the cost of importing the polyfills when the browser already has the required support.  Can you provide a repro case in Plunker?

Comment: Please post your full index

Comment: @Raspel There simply isn't enough information in the question to determine the problem, and guessing solutions wouldn't be very efficient. :) Please post a repro case in Plunker, or even provide a GitHub repo that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Raspel And to clarify, the script import is sufficient (even though not as optimized as the suggestion from the docs). You were right to assume that importing the polyfill would help. However, the root cause appears to be something else given that it didn't resolve your issue, so more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [polymer starter kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/index.html) , there in the index.html file shows how you should implement this functionality in order to load webcomponents-lite in a good way.

Comment: Tried copy-pasting the relevant script tag as first script in the head but its still not working in the latest firefox. Also I don't get any errors in the console. Not sure if I should.

Comment: Updated the original question with said snippet.

Comment: Is that in your index.html? Do you change your polymer.json and manifest.json the entrypoint to index?

Comment: Yes its in the first script tag in the head of my index.html and in my manifest.json index.html is my entrypoint.